# How to sign messages with Web3 and MetaMask from a React app

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask, ganache

I am working on my first dapp and I am trying to use Web3 and MetaMask to sign a message but I keep getting this error:

> inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: WalletMiddleware - Invalid "from" address.

I have the MetaMask privacy mode turned off. The getCoinBase() method is correctly returning the address I have selected in MetaMask. But when I try to use it to sign a message it does not work.

Here's my code: The lines of dots are to skip over the unimportant pieces.

```
let Web3 = require('web3')
.
.
.
constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    if (typeof web3 != 'undefined') {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef  
      this.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    }

    this.web3.eth.getCoinbase()
    .then(account => {
      this.web3.eth.sign('test message', account);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Metamask recently made changes about how they reveal addresses to users. I found a Stack Overflow post that seems related [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/65659/38266). To quote:

> The Invalid address error can also happen if you haven't called window.ethereum.enable(); yet.

Related blog post from Metamask team: https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but based on the blog post from the Metamask team I shouldn't have to call window.ethereum.enable(); if I have privacy mode turned off. Also, what is window.ethereum in this context? I don't have anything like that defined.

Comment: Also in the article, under section title `Preparing your dapp` it states: `As of MetaMask v4.14.0, the provider is already available at window.ethereum and it exposes the new enable method` and `dapps can and should be updated as soon as possible to call the new enable method to ensure compatibility with the upcoming change`. `window.ethereum` should be your web3 provider. I would make sure you have a fully up to date version of Metamask? I do agree about the privacy mode setting, but I can't help with that. May be best to ask about that on the Ethereum stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

```
   const accounts = (await ethereum?.request({
      method: "eth_requestAccounts",
    })) as string[];
    // account will be the signer of this message
    const account = accounts[0];
    
    const signedData = await ethereum?.request({
      method: "personal_sign",
      params: [
        JSON.stringify(messageToSign),
        account,
      ],
    });
```